Docusaurus: Filter /docs with "slug" on query parameters
I have three different documents in the /docs folder, and I would like to see only this document, whose folder is the name, displayed in the sidebar when accessing them via URL, for example: localhost:3000/docs/?slug=receitas.
I know it needs to be done on the "client-side" part of the project, but I have tried everything and have not been successful. I need help.
I tried some things I got from chatGpT but they didn't work. I need to know if there's something ready, because I don't believe that this, until today, was just a need of mine.
